# How to create a page and display only the posts with a specific custom field value?

Tags: pages, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to create a page (let's name it "Facebook") where i will display only the posts that has the custom field: "Facebook" and specifically the custom field value: "Yes".

P.S. 1. I would like to include the theme's header, slider, footer, sidebars etc.
     2. I use Advanced Custom Fields plugin

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content-wrap">
<div class="content">
    <?php tie_breadcrumbs() ?>

    <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div id="post-0" class="post not-found post-listing">
            <h1 class="post-title"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'tie' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="entry">
                <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'tie' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $get_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);  ?>
    <?php //Above Post Banner
    if( empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_above"][0] ) ){
        if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_banner_above"][0] ) ) echo '<div class="ads-post">' .htmlspecialchars_decode($get_meta["tie_banner_above"][0]) .'</div>';
        else tie_banner('banner_above' , '<div class="ads-post">' , '</div>' );
    }
    ?>

    <article class="post-listing post">
        <?php tie_include( 'post-head' ); // Get Post Head template ?>
        <div class="post-inner">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'tie' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>

                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'tie' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry /-->  

        </div><!-- .post-inner -->
    </article><!-- .post-listing -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php //Below Post Banner
    if( empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_below"][0] ) ){
        if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_banner_below"][0] ) ) echo '<div class="ads-post">' .htmlspecialchars_decode($get_meta["tie_banner_below"][0]) .'</div>';
        else tie_banner('banner_below' , '<div class="ads-post">' , '</div>' );
    }
    ?>

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
</div><!-- .content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate your `page.php` template, name the duplicate `page-facebook.php`, give it a template name:

```
/*
Template Name: My Facebook Meta Key Page
*/
```

More information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

To get the right posts with `get_posts` use something like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'facebook',
            'value' => 'yes',
        )
    )
 );
$fbposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($fbposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

More information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Of course you can do it with `WP_Query` like GhostToast suggested, it is pretty similar, take a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Get the posts with `WP_Query` like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'facebook',
            'value' => 'yes',
        )
    )
 );
$fbposts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $fbposts->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $fbposts->have_posts() ) {
  $fbposts->the_post();
      echo '<h2><a href="'. the_permalink() .'">'. the_title() .'</a></h2>';
      echo the_content();
  }
} else {

}
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Comment: do i have to change the:

`<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

With the code you gave me above?

Comment: It depends on which method you choose. Take a look at my answer and you will figure it out.

Comment: I tried inserting the code (with wp_query) you gave me instead of the `<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` but it gives me an error. Should i post in the question the theme's page.php code?

Comment: I corrected a bit of the code - it should work now, at least I can't see why not. You could post the code, but I'm gone any second now, and I'm certain you can figure it out!

Comment: Again it gives me an error. Please check the page.php code

Comment: @Charitos _"Gives me an error"_ is *not* a proper problem/error description.

Comment: @Charitos: The code GhostToast gave you should work, if all the parameters are correct - is the post type really post? Is the name of the custom field really facebook? Is the value really yes/no or is it maybe true/false? I personally think it is unlikely related to ACF, it is one of the good ones, well maintained and documented. I used the plugin several times and never had any problems querying anything i wanted. Like i said, the problem is probably somehow related to what you ask for in your query - if you configured everything else correctly, of course.

Comment: @ngsonst I think that the problem is the Greek characters that i use. You are right, i use the Greek Word "Ναι" (means yes) instead of the "Yes" value. When i tested with "yes" it worked fine. How can i fix it so i can use Greek letters/characters?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to learn how to [create a custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) and use a [meta_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). To ensure your new page template includes all the other elements you want, I would suggest starting by copying a template file (such as `page.php`) that works the way you want to already (as far as structure and includes). You're going to gut the `loop` section and write your own `wp_query`.

Welcome to the empowering side of WordPress!

Edit:

This is a modified version of the code you provided. Realize that you should, as @ngsonst suggested, you will want to save this as another file, such as `facebook-page.php`. You will then create a new page from the WordPress backend and assign it to this Template, which is named at the top of the file.

```
<?php
/****
Template Name: Facebook Page
****/

get_header(); ?>
<div class="content-wrap">
<div class="content">
    <?php tie_breadcrumbs();

    // define parameters for which posts we want
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => 'facebook',
            'value' => 'yes',
            )
        )
    );

    // create new instance of wp_query, the object which loops through posts
    $loop = new wp_query($args);

    // as long as it has posts, set current post up and do all of the following
    while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();

        $get_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        //Above Post Banner
        if( empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_above"][0] ) ){
            if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_banner_above"][0] ) ) echo '<div class="ads-post">' .htmlspecialchars_decode($get_meta["tie_banner_above"][0]) .'</div>';
            else tie_banner('banner_above' , '<div class="ads-post">' , '</div>' );
        }
        ?>
        <article class="post-listing post">
            <?php tie_include( 'post-head' ); // Get Post Head template ?>
            <div class="post-inner">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="entry">
                    <?php 
                    // get title as permalink
                    echo '<h2><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h2>';
                    // get content
                    the_content();
                    wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'tie' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); 

                    edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'tie' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry /-->  

            </div><!-- .post-inner -->
        </article><!-- .post-listing -->

    <?php
    // end our loop
    endwhile; 

    //Below Post Banner
    if( empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_below"][0] ) ){
        if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_banner_below"][0] ) ) echo '<div class="ads-post">' .htmlspecialchars_decode($get_meta["tie_banner_below"][0]) .'</div>';
        else tie_banner('banner_below' , '<div class="ads-post">' , '</div>' );
    }


    comments_template( '', true ); ?>
</div><!-- .content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Realize that I have no idea what the `tie_breadcrumbs` stuff is, and have no way of knowing if it will work with this. You could easily gut all those parts, but wanted to leave that for you to discover. Let us know how this works out.

Comment: In the page.php there is nowhere the word loop.

Do i have to look for:

'<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>'

?

Comment: That will work, yes.

Comment: So i have to change the `<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

with something like this:

`<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'facebook',
            'value' => 'yes',
        )
    )
 );
$fbposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($fbposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: sure looks good to me. That should create a list of links to the posts you want. I prefer `wp_query` but that is partly preference. Assuming "facebook" meta field is defined as "yes" when selected.

Comment: i wrote the theme's page.php code in the main question. Please take a look and tell me where do i have to insert the code?

Comment: It is not always so simple as replacing one bit of code with another. You must understand what is happening. I will rewrite your code in my answer so you can see what should work. One moment.

Comment: Thanks! I really would like what happening when changing a code..Explain me!

Comment: Thank you @GhostToast, but it really didn't work! I can't understand why.. I use Advanced Custom Fields plugin, may be that the problem?

Comment: I've never used that plugin. You should try and discover what value is actually being held within your custom field. If you edit the post in question, you should be able to use Chrome or Firefox's inspector to find the value associated with the meta box. Is it "yes" ? or something else? And perhaps because my code says "yes" instead of "Yes" ? Time to put on your detective hat a bit.

Comment: I tried both uppercase and lowercase but didn't work. What did you mean about the Chrome inspector? I think that it is only for CSS inspecting.

Comment: You should be able to see the value of the form element with it. Such as `<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" />` or something. Might need to investigate the FAQ of the CMB plugin you are using.

Comment: here is the documentation for the wp_query of the ACF plugin.

[link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-query-posts-filtered-by-custom-field-values/)

Comment: No offense @Charitos but that is something you need to read. Time for a little detective work. Try modifying the code you've been given a little at a time and see what you can return. Use debugging tricks/tools to examine your output and see why you're not getting what you want.

Comment: You are right! Can you only help me how to insert examine it? Are there tools?

Comment: @GhostToast: I support your effort to help someone to enable themselfs! Charitos: Reading/information is key for understanding which leads to realisation (psychic and physical), but I have the feeling that is a nearly philosophical topic or at least a life lesson, and here isn't the place for that... ;)